# Tail recursive Map function RACKET

Tags: recursion, racket, tail-recursion

The map function in Racket takes a function and a list and applies the function to each of the items of the list recursively. I'm trying to convert the map into a tail-recursive function, how can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

Where are you getting stuck? You can define your own `map` procedure with an inner `loop` procedure.

```scm
(define (map f in)
  (define (loop out lst)
    (if #|exit condition here|#
        #|return output|#
        (loop (cons #|add to output|# out)
              #|sub problem|#)))
  (loop null in)) ; run the loop

(map (lambda (x) (* x x)) '(1 2 3 4 5))
```

```scm
'(1 4 9 16 25)
```

This pattern is so common in racket that there is a named `let` syntax that makes it easier for us to use.

```scm
(define (map f in)
  (let loop ((out null) (lst in))
    (if #|exit condition here|#
        #|return output|#
        (loop (cons #|add to output|# out)
              #|sub problem|#))))
```

Another option is to use continuations.

```scm
(define (map f in)
  (let (loop (return identity) (lst in))
    (if #|exit condition|#
        (return null)
        (loop (lambda (out) (return (cons #|add to output|# out)))
              #|sub problem|#))))
```