# Map function Tail recursive

Tags: recursion, racket, tail-recursion

How can I make the map function tail recursive? I have this implementation but I wonder if I can do it differently

```
(define (map f lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      '()
      (cons (f (first lst)) (map f (rest lst)))))
```

Comment: Is this french, vulgar, or assembly?

Comment: You have already asked this question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71161788/tail-recursive-map-function-racket. Please don't ask a repeated question. If the answer in that question was not satisfying, you should leave some clarifying comments.